# Performance issues on Next.js SSR building initial page from api

Tags: next.js

We have developed a Next.js app. The home page takes several seconds (7s) before initial load, thereafter requesting any additional artifacts. We call the menu and a headless api for the body. The API is fronted with Cloudflare and is part of getServerSideProps. We do use proxy middleware to call the apis.

How can we identify long running threads on SSR? Any performance optimization tips we can use?